# PHP Session lost after redirect; comes back after refresh

Tags: php

I have a login code that had been working fine for a couple years. No code was changed, and the server hosts claim that nothing was changed that would effect sessions.

Here's the basic run-down:

```
1. User enters login info

2. Sent to process.php
   - Sets a $_SESSION['userid'] variable if validation was successful
   - Redirected back to previous page (using exit after header())

3. $_SESSION['userid'] is not set.

4. Refresh Page.

5. $_SESSION['userid'] is now set properly.
```

All pages have `session_start()`. I've also tried using `session_regenerate_id(true);` and `session_write_close();` Nothing Has changed.

Any ideas on server configuration or errors in my code would be welcome.

Comment: try redirecting the user to a different url than the previous one, it could be a browser cache issue

Comment: session cookies (as all cookies) are extremely sensetivte to any data before headers. Make the request with curl or similar and watch for UTF8-BOM's and other stuff that may mess up set session-setup.

Comment: edit: It could be cache issue, I have mixed results when redirecting to different pages.. Any ideas on fixing something like this?

Comment: At first it works, but it appears to not work after the first try.

Comment: Redirect to the same page including a random parameter e.g. formerPage.php?trash=97ydf9sbdf97

Comment: @Alfabravo This does solve this issue.. Any idea why this happening all the sudden and how I may fix it long term?

Comment: I support the "cache problem" approach that many others told you before. Probably someone changed the server config, some htaccess changed and added your .php files to the cacheable stuf... maybe your users migrated to the powerful and too-smartass IE7 or IE8 and it tries to be as lazy as it can, hence it reads an URL and, if you go forward and backwards in browser's history with JS, IE won't reload the page. Even if you call it with php location header, IE probably will give you a cached version. Pure laziness and the workaround is changing the URL every single time so it has to load it again